# A way to add parameters to variables or something so I don't spam functions and vars

Tags: javascript, parameters, parameter-passing

So the point of this, game like, website JavaScript is creating triggers. The Const pgUnlock is the on and off switch. I want it so that when the viewer clicks on a button, I will change the element to turn the false into a true. For example, below, it checks if the number 1 is in the [0] index and if it is, it'll unlock a new part of the website, by replacing the # with the next page link. The function 'alertbox()' checks this and if the trigger isn't on, it'll make a button visible, letting the player know that the "page is locked". So my question is how do I add parameters to consolidate the code so I'm not creating 5 more 'alertbox()' functions because the 'check' var has to be customized for each placement for 'pgUnlock'. If not, I'm fine with repeating the code, I just want to see if I/we can keep everything performance friendly by using cleaner code, as I'm not that familiar with JavaScript. To let you know how dumb I am, one of my tries was: 'var check(x,y)= pgUnlock.includes(x,y);'

```
var a = document.querySelector('.rebtn[href="#"]');
const pgUnlock= [0,0,0,0,0];
var check= pgUnlock.includes(1,0);
var check2= pgUnlock.includes(2,0);
var check3= pgUnlock.includes(3,0);
var check4= pgUnlock.includes(4,0);
var check5= pgUnlock.includes(5,0);

if (check==true) {
  a.setAttribute('href', './introPage.html');
} 

reBtn.onclick=()=>{
    alertbox();
}

legBtn.onclick=()=>{
    alertbox();
}

godBtn.onclick=()=>{
    alertbox();
}

chgBtn.onclick=()=>{
    alertbox();
}

ch2Btn.onclick=()=>{
    alertbox();
}

function alertbox(){
    if(check==false){
        alertBtn.classList.add("visalert");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not knowing is not dumb. We read, we learn, we fail, we read more, we learn more, we succeed.

Comment: I'm sorry but i do not understand your goal.

Comment: So I will have to multiple alertbox( ) functions. Because I have to create one with check2==false, check3==false and so on. Is there a way to change the function to umbrella all of the check vars?

Comment: `function alertbox( parameter1 ) {}
ch2Btn.onclick=()=>{
    alertbox(BooleanToCheckifThisIstur);
}`

Comment: My second problem is the vars themselves. Is there a way to use parameters to umbrella all the vars under one as well? For example if: var check(x,y) = pgUnlock.includes(x,y)    Then I can do alertbox(x,y) to have it pass into the check(x,y).

Comment: `var check(x,y)` will not work, where is the x and y value coming from ?

Comment: Can you add your button html, i think i am starting to see what your goal is

Comment: the x and y is coming from the .includes( ). I thought it would trinkle down from alertbox(x,y) to fill in the check(x,y), to fill in the .includes(x,y)?

Comment: Ok ok, i start to see now...

Comment: First of all, is that how you want to use Array.includes ? Array includes got 2 parameters,  searchElement and fromIndex, you are looking for `1` from index 0 till end.

Comment: if not mistaken::  Step 1 : ` check = pgUnlock.map( (x) => { return Boolean(x); }) `

Comment: This will give check[0] with a boolean value as return true or false.

Comment: If you do not want a check[0], you can do pgUnlock= [null, 0,0,0,1,0];

Comment: I'm not really sure of a better way. I'm using my Python knowledge for it. for python I can just make a list called cars and just ask, " if 'x' in cars..." I'll add in photos for a better idea of what I'm working with. I don't want to just copy and paste long lines of code when its easier for you just to glance at it.

Comment: Now i see what you want, you have the in operator as such in JavaScript

Comment: I'll look for it and I'll also try it your way as it's something I have to learn sooner or later

Comment: `1 in [1,2,3,4,5]; //true 6 in [1,2,3,4,5]; //false`  the in operator is more advanced in python but for any object you can use the in operator in javascript, array is an object

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you! I looked up the in operator and somehow got directed to .includes lol.

Comment: Haha,   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: Now i start to get confused :P

Comment: welp, Imma just delete this question like it never happened. Thanks a ton for answering back. Have a good one!

Comment: button.onclick=(event) => { console.log(event.currentTarget) }

Comment: If you fill you anchor element with a data attribute then you can fetch it in event.currentTarget.dataset

Comment: That way you can make 1 event listener for all buttons and in the event changes the check depending on de data attribute

Comment: If I understand this right. So it'll store the value of it being true or false and I can use that as a trigger itself? and that way all false will make the alert button appear and if true with the given Id I can specifically make another function as the buttons do different stuff?

Comment: Yes, ` <a data-locked="true" class="disabled">very fancy button</a>`

Comment: `thatNiceAndStrongSexyButton.onclick=(event)=>{  if(event.currentTarget.dataset.locked == "true") {//locked}  }`



    alertbox();
}

Comment: Let me make a codepen, all that stuff in comments :P

Comment: I wish I had higher reputation so we didn't have to do this the hard way lol. Can't use the chat yet.

Comment: No worries, we will get there, looking for my codepen pwd

Comment: the dataset.locked =="true" is coming from the data-locked="true", but what is the {//locked} doing?

Comment: https://codepen.io/PhilAndelhofs/pen/JjJMXJM

Comment: data-*  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: This is a thousand times better. It's like having a padlock on it instead of digging through a box of old miscellaneous momentos

Comment: Haha, i really have to go now, if you have any more questions feel free to mail.
`//stackoverflow@pandelhofs.be`